# Assets images disappear after site move

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

The site in question has had its domain changed and files moved to a new spot on the server. The site loads, but all Assets image fields in entries have not retained their images. However, image thumbnails do appear in the Assets file manager.

EE2.7.2, Assets 2.2.2, Matrix 2.5.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason, the exp_assets_selections table became blank and some point in the process. I restored a backup of the DB, and it works now.

For future ref: if Assets barfs, make sure there is data in the appropriate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the paths in Content -> Files -> File Upload Preferences?

Comment: Yes, I have updated those paths.